# How to split a string into key-value pairs via new line dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, split

string format

```
addr,hname,beam,txrate,rxrate,dcap,ucap,txuse,rxuse,rxrssi0,rxrssi1,txrssi0,txrssi1,txper,rxper,txopqual
04:18:D6:bb:F4:C6,Name,0,270000,270000,295650,263250,31,17,35,36,37,35,124,229,0
```

desired output

```
addr = 04:18:D6:bb:F4:C6
hname = Name
beam = 0
```

and so on ...
...
i would like to pair in t key value but the key is a new line form the value and put them into a Dictionary for output use this code works, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do this that will skip empty values

this is what i have so far

```
Dictionary<string, string> INFO =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
var terminal = client.RunCommand("amstainfo");
var output = terminal.Result;
string[] line = output.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string[] KEY = line[0].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string[] VALUE = line[1].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int i = 0;
foreach (var ist in KEY)
{
    INFO.Add(KEY[i], VALUE[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` instead of `StringSplitOptions.None`

Comment: @EZI That will reorder the values. Key-Value assosiation will be lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems fairly straight forward like this:

```
var lines = text.Split(
    Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(),
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var INFO =
    lines[0].Split(',')
        .Zip(lines[1].Split(','), (key, value) => new { key, value })
        .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.value))
        .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```

This gives:

[image: result]

Comment: Aren't there are some typos to correct in this answer? Bracket after `where` and 2 times `.ToDictionary`.

Comment: @Marwie - Sorry, I stuffed up a basic edit. I've fixed it.

Comment: @Oluwafemi - It's fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

You can include an if statement in the foreach loop to check if the value is not empty or null before adding it to the dictionary.

```
foreach (var ist in KEY)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(VALUE[i]))
    {
       INFO.Add(KEY[i], VALUE[i]);
    }
    i++;
}
```